# Erro 500 ao realizar o download de um xlm via iframe;

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde, tenho uma aplicação WEB com EXTJS com a opção de exportar um relatorio no formato XML através de um POST via ashx, atualmente um dos clientes que tem essa aplicação está reportando um problema no minimo peculiar. O mesmo não está conseguindo exportar o arquivo e o retorno é um erro 500;

Aqui está a construção do iframe:

```
    _exportarFormulario: function ()
    {
        var body = Ext.getBody();

        if (!this.frameExportarHidden)
        {
            this.frameExportarHidden = body.createChild({
                 tag:'iframe'
                ,cls:'x-hidden'
                ,id:'iframeExportar'
                ,name:'iframeExportar'
            });
        }

        if (!this.formExportarHidden)
        {
            this.formExportarHidden = body.createChild({
                 tag:'form'
                ,cls:'x-hidden'
                ,id:'formExportar'
                ,method: 'POST'
                ,action: "FormularioImportacao.ashx?sessionID=0E72435340AE43C48293922D17C2CB06&fnTarget=ExportarFormulario&formularioId=646"
                ,target:'iframeExportar'
            });
        }

        this.formExportarHidden.dom.submit();
    }
```

Dentro do FormularioImportacao.ashx eu tenho o medo que irá processar a requisição.

```
    public class FormularioImportacao : IHttpHandler
    {
          protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        String fnTarget = context.Request["fnTarget"];
        //recupera a informação do método usando reflection
        MethodInfo methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(fnTarget, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        try
        {
            methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { context });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string erro = e.Message;
            if (e.InnerException != null)
                erro = e.InnerException.Message;
            context.Response.Write("{'success': false, 'mensagem': '" + erro.Replace("'", "\"") + "'}");
        }
    }

    // E respectivamente, o metodo para exportar o formulário 
    private void ExportarFormulario(HttpContext context)
    {
        int formularioId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["formularioId"]);
        Formulario formulario = new Formulario();

        try
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            context.Response.Charset = "iso-8859-1";
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"FRM_" + formularioId.ToString() + ".xml\"");
            context.Response.Write(formulario.ExportarFormulario(formularioId));
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            log.Error(null, e);
        }
    }
```

o problema, é que mesmo com try/catch não me gera log de erro apenas me dá o erro da imagem abaixo:

[image: Erro mistico sem explicação.]

Meu maior problema é que não estou entendo o que diabos está acontecendo aqui...
Eu deveria ter setado o tamanho máximo no header? é alguma treta no iss, mas se for isso não deveria dar um erro especifico do IIS ao invés do 500? Alguma dica?

Answer (score -1):

Tem uma resposta semelhante no StackOverflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940268/ashx-handler-return-500-internal-server-error

Resumindo: coloque no web.config a entrada:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Para mostrar o que acontece.